# Windows Firewall wont stay off

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

I have a Freenas server which i need to connect to. However i can only do this when windows firewall is disabled. I have another more controllable firewall installed. I have search for days and with every solution i have found, firewall will turn itself back on especially while i am using my server. Every time i turn my computer back on i have to spend at least 30 min fighting this stupid firewall before i can even use my NAS. Please help because linux is looking better and better every day but Adobe doesn't run on linux ! Thanks!

Comment: “I have search for days and with every solution” - You will need to provide additional details.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10, you can turn off windows defender firewall by going to `Control Panel -> System and Security -> Windows Firewall -> Turn Windows Firewall on or off -> Turn off Windows Firewall (not recommended)` as described in this article [here](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-disable-the-windows-firewall-2624505)

Comment: It turns itself back on! Thank you for responding!

Comment: @ojo360 Do you get an alert message when you turn it off? If so, is there any way to see if the program you are running is starting it for you? You can also try modifying the rules to allow traffic through the ports you need.